# Tab complete from :open in Macvim?

Tags: text-editor, vim, macvim, tab-completion

If I open MacVim (specifically [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)) and try `:open ~/<TAB>` I get `:open ~/^I`.  How can I get it to tab complete the way one would expect bash completion to work?

Comment: `:open` is not the command for opening files; it is a residual command left over from the original *ex* where it invoked a single-line “visual” mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use :

```
:e ~/<TAB>
```

`:set wildmenu` would also be very helpful.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I had `:set wildmenu` but I didn't realize `:open` was the wrong thing to do.